# how does one compute expectations for non-linear functions

Tags: bayesian, expected-value, integral, variational-bayes

I am continuing my struggles with approximate Bayesian inference methods. I have a fundamental doubt about how to compute certain expectations that arise during variational bayes, for example.

So, my joint model is written as:

$$
p(Y|W, \beta, X) = \prod_{i=1}^{N} p(y_i|x_i, w_i, \beta) p(w_i)p(\beta)
$$

Here $W$ and $\beta$ are the model parameters and $W= \{w_i, w_2, w_3....w_i\}$ and i is the i-th observation. $y_i$ is the i-th output variable and $x_i$ is the corresponding input.

So I have applied Variational Bayes and and factorized my model parameters according to the mean field approximation as $Q(W, \beta) = Q(W)Q(\beta)$. So, now if I want the posterior distribution over $Q(W)$, I have to take the expectation wrt to the $Q(\beta)$. So, looking at each $w_i$ in the first instance, I have:

$$
p(y_i, w_i, \beta| x_i) = p(y_i|x_i, w_i, \beta) p(w_i)p(\beta)
$$

Consequently,

$$
\log Q(w_i) = E_{\beta}[\log p(y_i|x_i, w_i, \beta) + \log p(w_i) + \log p(\beta)]
$$

where $E[\beta]$ represents the expectation wrt to $Q(\beta)$

Taking constant terms out:

$$
\log Q(w_i) = E_{\beta}[\log p(y_i|x_i, w_i, \beta) + \log p(w_i)] + C 
$$

My problem now is that the first term is modeled using a Gaussian distribution but the parameters $\beta$ are connects $y_i$ and $x_i$ through a non-linear transformation function. So, in the end I end up with having to compute integral of the expression of the form:

$$
E_{\beta}[y-T(x)]^T[y-T(x)]\big]
$$

Assuming $Q(\beta)$ takes some known form, how may I proceed to compute this expectation given that $T$ can be any arbitrary function?

Comment: Unless you have an exact form for $T(x)$, this question makes no sense.

Comment: Why is that? Surely numerical ways exist to integrate this for arbitrary $T$

Comment: Depending on the dimensionality of beta I would be tempted to use a Monte Carlo estimate of the expectation you need.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the only way to compute expectations for *arbitrary* functions is to use sampling (Monte Carlo methods). E.g. you gather samples from the joint posterior distribution and expectation turns into simply averaging the value of $T$ over the samples.

If you want an analytic solution, you IMHO need a specific form of $T$ and use your calculus to find the integral.